# ViewManager.GetViewsOfViewModel always return null

Tags: c#, mvvm, catel

I'm trying to use Catel ViewManager to registering and getting view but I don't get View from ViewManager.GetViewsOfViewModel

As I understand it, a when the UserControl is unloaded from the visual tree it is destroyed but this should not happen becouse I use CloseViewModelOnUnloaded = false;

I made a small example to demonstrate this problem. [TestApp](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/ILczIeRSHYhv2agSH0OoIk1Da3uzjrLIWVB6466HK8v?ref_=cd_share_link_copy)

```
 public void ShowDocumentWindow<TViewModel>(object model = null) where TViewModel : DocumentItemViewModel
    {
        IViewModel vm = null;

        if (model != null)
        {
            vm = this.viewModelManager.GetViewModelsOfModel(model).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        if (vm == null)
        {
            var viewModel = this.viewModelFactory.CreateViewModel<TViewModel>(model);
            var viewType = this.viewLocator.ResolveView(viewModel.GetType());

            var view = Activator.CreateInstance(viewType, viewModel);

            this.documentHost.Items.Add(new DocumentPanel
            {
                Content = view,
                IsActive = true,
                MDIState = MDIState.Normal
            });

            this.viewManager.RegisterView((IView)view); // Registering 
            this.viewModelManager.RegisterModel(viewModel, model);
        }
        else
        {
            var view = this.viewManager.GetViewsOfViewModel(vm).FirstOrDefault() as UserControl; \\ but this I get null

            var index = this.documentHost.Items.FindIndex(x =>
            {
                var documentPanel = x as DocumentPanel;
                if (documentPanel != null)
                {
                    return Equals(documentPanel.Content, view);
                }

                return false;
            });

            this.documentHost.SelectedTabIndex = index;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you create an example without 3rd party components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view gets removed from the "active views" (inside the ViewManager) as soon as it is unloaded. That it keeps its view model in memory for when it is being loaded again doesn't change the fact that the view is currently not being used.

One solution is to create your own IViewManager (everything is pluggable in Catel), then you can somehow create a "threshold period" where views are not really removed so they have a chance to be reloaded.

But... I think it's better to store state inside a service / memory object and restore that and create a new VM when you load the view again.